# How to check active Shopify stores subscriptions using GraphQL and API?

Tags: laravel, graphql, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I have a Shopify application that is installed on multiple Shopify stores, and I need to programmatically check which stores have an active subscription plan using the Shopify API and GraphQL.

I want to perform the following tasks:

1. Retrieve a list of all the Shopify stores that have installed my
   application.
2. For each store in the list, check if they have an active subscription plan, and if so, retrieve details about the subscription plan.

I understand that Shopify provides GraphQL APIs to interact with store data, but I'm not sure which specific queries and endpoints to use for this purpose.

Can someone please provide guidance or sample code on how to achieve this using Shopify's GraphQL and API?

Comment: It seems impossible that you made an App and yet you have no clue how API calls work? Can you better explain in your question your background so as to help the community understand how to help you?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I inherited the app from previous developers, and I’ve sorted out how to identify the stores installed with our app. However, the challenge is determining which stores have active our app’s subscription plans and which don’t. The database isn’t well-managed. Is there an API or GraphQL solution for this?

Comment: There is. You can easily use the token Shopify issued to each store to ask about the current subscriptions. Lucky you!

Comment: I was searching for a solution just like the one you provided, and I'm delighted to say I've found it! I already had the tokens in place, but I needed the specific approach you mentioned. Using the GET /admin/recurring_application_charges.json endpoint has allowed me to easily determine which stores have active subscription plans for my application. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction – it was exactly what I needed!